# staring and killing evince process in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have certain PDF files. I want to inspect each of them for 20 seconds. The way I was trying to do that is like following: `for file in *.pdf; do echo $file; evince $file; sleep 20s; killall evince; done` . It displays the first file, but does not kill it after 20s. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start `evince` asynchronously so that the `sleep` gets to run:

```
for file in *.pdf; do
    echo $file;
    evince $file & sleep 20s;
    killall evince;
done
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested, this is better:

```
for file in *.pdf; do
   evince "$file" & evince_pid=$!
   sleep 20s
   kill $evince_pid
done
```

Comment: `evince "$file" & evince_pid=$!; sleep 20s; kill $evince_pid` won't accidentally kill any other `evince` processes.

Comment: Thanks, that's wonderful. Gonna accept @wilx's answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `timeout` (part of GNU coreutils) if available:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    echo "$f"
    timeout 20 evince "$file"
done
```